# Selenium Chromedriver or gekodriver or edgedriver not reachable

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-edgedriver

I have recently started using VS2022 and I wanted to upgrade the .NET framework to .NET 6.0. After installing all the required components as given below. I wrote a sample chrome launch code. The automation opens chrome however it closes the window with 'Chrome not reachable' error. I get similar issue with Firefox and Edge drivers as well.

**Code:**

```
         ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver("\\chromedriver.exe", options, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(3));     
       public void GivenIAmOnHomepage() { ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
```

```
     options.AddArgument("--no-sandbox");

        //var driverService = FirefoxDriverService.CreateDefaultService();

        //FirefoxOptions FirefoxOptions = new FirefoxOptions();

        //FirefoxOptions.AddArgument("start-maximized");
        //driverService.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;

        //driver = new FirefoxDriver(driverService, FirefoxOptions, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(220));
        //driver.ExecuteJavaScript("Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'webdriver', {get: () => undefined})");
    }
```

**StackTrace**:

```
OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverExceptionHResult=0x80131500Message=chrome not reachableSource=WebDriverStackTrace:at OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse, String commandToExecute)at OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)at OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriver.StartSession(ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)at OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriver..ctor(ICommandExecutor executor, ICapabilities capabilities)at OpenQA.Selenium.Chromium.ChromiumDriver..ctor(ChromiumDriverService service, ChromiumOptions options, TimeSpan commandTimeout)at OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver..ctor(ChromeDriverService service, ChromeOptions options, TimeSpan commandTimeout)at OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver..ctor(String chromeDriverDirectory, ChromeOptions options, TimeSpan commandTimeout)at SpecflowSelenium_net6_POC.StepDefinitions.CorporateWebsiteStepDefinitions.GivenIAmOnBCUHomepage() in C:\Users****\source\repos\SpecflowSelenium_net6_POC\SpecflowSelenium_net6_POC\StepDefinitions\CorporateWebsiteStepDefinitions.cs:line 25
```

**Bug raised on Github:**
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/11985